# selenium element not interactable

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

i started using selenuim, node js

it was working all perfect so far, sudenly the same script is throwing and error

"unhandled promise rejection warning element not interactable"

i tried setting  wait, until and nothing

```
<script>

  const {Builder, By, Key, until, wait } = require('selenium-webdriver');

  var driver = new Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.build();


 driver.manage().window().maximize() 
 driver.get('http://www.google.com/testsite')
driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('test@emal');
driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys('passowrod');
driver.findElement(By.className('acceder')).click();
driver.quit();


</script>
```

i search all over but all examples simply did not work for me, due that they dont have that issues,..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6qQojzN7bE&index=4&list=PLA4JPGpQHctT__mDO9EHvOrWVW0Hkf5Mk

Comment: Is that your working example? The URL provided (https://www.google.com/testsite) generates a 404.

Comment: Would you please check the element with classname "acceder" exist before you click?? Or would you post your HTML here?

Comment: driver.get('https://www.exclusivetravelerclub.com/en/home-login?redirect=exclusive-resorts/catalonia-royal-la-romana?&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Retencion%20Feb2019%20USA&utm_term=Gold&utm_content=Noches4x3%20CRR');                                        ............ that is the currect url, this lies on that it doesnt event do anything after the page is loaded

Comment: From my understanding, you're trying to access the element whose class name is `boton acceder`. However, there are multiple elements with that class name, and therefore you will need to use the `xpath()` method. Try replacing `By.className('acceder'))` with `By.xpath("(//button[@class='boton acceder'])[1]")`. I cannot predict which index will do the trick, you'll have to try it yourself.

Comment: the issue is not the click by itself, the sendKeys doesnt work either

Comment: Been over this for a few hours, and managed to get the username field filled but it would get stuck in the password step. It's odd because by calling the `getText()` function, an empty string is returned, even if the object exists. By the way, the consideration I made about multiple objects with the same class name, also exists with the ID, since 2 elements share both the `username` and `password` IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These locators worked for me for the url you shared:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('(//input[@id="username"])[2]')).sendKeys('test@emal');
driver.findElement(By.xpath('(//input[@id="password"])[2]')).sendKeys('passowrod');
driver.findElement(By.xpath('(//button[@class="boton acceder"])[2]')).click();
```

The reason for using 2nd index for all the elements is that the same elements are in HEADER which are hidden.

Note: I tried these in python, so please adjust if any string syntax error.

Comment: it did worked for me, for some reason only by.xpath work, by.id or by.cssSelector doesnt. but thansk alot

Comment: Yes, because when you use id or cssSelector, it would find the first match from top of page and that is not shown in UI. So to get the second result, I had to use xpath with index of 2.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**:  While running the automation, the window size is is not fully presented on screen so some elements are rendered outside of the visible area in your configured chrome web driver.

**The solution** would be using this snippet in your base configuration:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```