# Selenium - Error: element not interactable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Need:** Update fields on url & click button using Selenium (Screenshot of Webpage & HTML details below)

**Issue:** Returns an error as shown below

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
element not interactable

(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
```

**Research:** I referred to the following but was unable to fix it - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870871/selenium-element-not-interactable) [Link2](https://www.qtpselenium.com/selenium-training/forum/getting-orgopenqaseleniumelementnotinteractableexception-element-not-interactable-error-4566)

**Code:** Based on the suggestions in other links have added Wait & also sleep, but still not working.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'User ID')]"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Password')]"));
new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
email.sendKeys("myemail@gmail.com");
```

**HTML & WebPage View:**
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV9wR.jpg)

Hope the issue faced is clear, await guidance.

Comment: are you sure //label[contains(text(),'User ID')] element is present on UI after launching your url?

Comment: @DebanjanB no it does not. Before marking my query as duplicate if you had seen the error message you would've known. I had checked that link before posting. Anyway the answer by Ayaz (first option) resolves this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try any of following xpath

```
//label[contains(text(),'User ID')]/following-sibling::input

//input[@placeholder='User ID']
```

your xpath is targeting label. You need to locate `<input>`

Comment: Not sure why moderator has marked it as duplicate. Anyone facing this issue use the first option suggested by Ayaz (i.e. /following-sibling), that works, not the 2nd one.